# Array to string conversion - Project Crash [Laravel]

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am getting an error like this:

> Array to string conversion

Inside:

> /var/.../vendor/cartalyst/sentry/src/Cartalyst/Sentry/SentryServiceProvider.php

Code snippet where the error was thrown:

> throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Invalid hasher [$hasher] chosen for Sentry.");

I was doing ordianry work in one of my controllers and this error occured when I clicked on one of the buttons inside my blade.

I have commented the code out but the error still is being displayed, not only on this one page but on every single one in my project. I can't even go to my /home/index.php page.

I have done

> composer update

inside my project but that did not help. What can fix the problem?

**@update**

Yes I have checked sentry config file before I've made a new topic. I have the same problem when I load older versions (which do not contain the latest changes I've made today) of my project on to apache server which is running on Ubuntu 14.04.

Ideas what causes the problem?

Comment: You may want to add the full stack error from your laravel.log file to your question :)

Comment: `$hasher`is an array?

Comment: @cmnardi I guess $hasher comes from sentry configuration which I haven't touched at all.

Answer (score 0):

In the config for Sentry you have to define a hasher.
It has to be a string. It can be 'native', 'bcrypt', 'sha256' or 'whirlpool'. Apparently in your app, it's not a string, but an array. Check your configuration. It's probably in app/config/packages/cartalyst/sentry/config.php

Comment: This is what I got: 'hasher' => 'sha256'  I have just loaded one of my backup on to the apache server and the same problem occurs... The backup did not contain latest changes so it should work fine... It must be something else that fails everything.. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: The easiest thing would be to use XDebug or Zend Debugger and set a breakpoint in the line that fails and examine the value that's set. Then walk up the backtrace path to figure out where the wrong value came from.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. I will try to do that however the same problem occurs when I load the older version of my project. Do you think it could be something else that it's causing it?

Comment: I'm quite certain the config is broken. If your IDE won't let you debug, do you at least have a local installation on which you can test? In this case I'd put a var_dump($hasher) right before the throw new \InvalidArgumentException line

Comment: But how it broke on all my backups at once? they were not even touched or modified and they were working well previously. I am getting worried now. var_dump($hasher) does not want to work. The same error gets displayed.

Comment: Strange that the var_dump won't work. Difficult to tell from here. Maybe an error in the host entry (either your hosts file, C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts on Windows, or /etc/hosts on Linux) or the vhost file if you're using virtual host names, so that the code that's being executed is not where you think it is? To be absolutely sure, use a die('this line got executed') where you put your var_dump, because I find it unlikely that var_dump would fail. It sounds rather like the line isn't being executed at all. Have you also cleared all caches?

Comment: I've done die(var_dump($hasher)); and the result is: array(0) { } . I haven't clear the caches. Should I run: sync && echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches ??

Comment: No, I meant using the Laravel cli commands: php artisan cache:clear  and php artisan config:clear

Comment: Just done cache:clear but still having Array to string conversion error. I guess it is not picking up this line: $hasher = $app['config']['cartalyst/sentry::hasher'];

Comment: Maybe you still need to run this command? php artisan config:publish cartalyst/sentry

Comment: Tried to publish it again but there is the same problem.. Any other ideas?

Comment: It looks like the config of Sentry is not being picked up properly. When I hardcode $hasher = 'sha256' inside SentryServiceProvider.php it kinda works however I get Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException when I try to login as one of my users inside the project.. It might be something to do with the boot order? SentryServiceProvider is booted before the config? Any ideas?