# Laravel 4 - Sentry config.php not found?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, sentry

I have a very strange problem with my project which have occured during my day-to-day, ordinary work. I am getting an "Array to string conversion" error which appears on every single page of my project. SentryServiceProvider.php throws this:

```
throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Invalid hasher [$hasher] chosen for Sentry.");
```

I have done some debugging and it looks like value $hasher is null. When I've tried to hardcode value $hasher like this:

```
//$hasher = $app['config']['cartalyst/sentry::hasher'];

$hasher = 'sha256';
```

It kinda worked fine however I was getting different query exceptions - I guess this is because it couldn't find other sentry configurations. With my understanding, Sentry configuration file which is founded in app>config>packages>cartalyst>sentry  is not being picked up properly. Any ideas why this happens?

I am reffering back to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39144324/array-to-string-conversion-project-crash-laravel)

Here is the section which causes the error:

```
class SentryServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

/**
 * Boot the service provider.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    $this->package('cartalyst/sentry', 'cartalyst/sentry', __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/cartalyst');
}

/**
 * Register the service provider.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    $this->registerHasher();
    $this->registerUserProvider();
    $this->registerGroupProvider();
    $this->registerThrottleProvider();
    $this->registerSession();
    $this->registerCookie();
    $this->registerSentry();
}

/**
 * Register the hasher used by Sentry.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function registerHasher()
{
    $this->app['sentry.hasher'] = $this->app->share(function($app)
    {
        $hasher = $app['config']['cartalyst/sentry::hasher'];



        switch ($hasher)
        {
            case 'native':
                return new NativeHasher;
                break;

            case 'bcrypt':
                return new BcryptHasher;
                break;

            case 'sha256':
                return new Sha256Hasher;
                break;

            case 'whirlpool':
                return new WhirlpoolHasher;
                break;
        }


        throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Invalid hasher [$hasher] chosen for Sentry.");
    });
}
```

Comment: Did you try to republish your Sentry config? And then to clear chache.

Comment: @Viktor Yes I've tried that but still having the same issue.

Comment: As an option, try to remove cache manyally.

Comment: @Viktor Just so I do this right, I need to clear contents from app/storage/cache and app/storage/meta?

Comment: ```sudo rm -rf app/storage/cache/```.

Comment: @Viktor So I've done publish first and then manually removed cache however the issue did not disappear.

Comment: It's difficult to figure out. Did you add some libraries throught composer?

Comment: @Viktor I did not add anything. I was only doing ordinary work on my project. The funny thing is, I have the same issue with all of my backups which previously worked fine.

Comment: Hmm, leter, you will figure out, that is trivial problem or some typo.)
Why you using Sentry? If I understood, right now library is deprecated -  https://github.com/cartalyst/sentry/tree/v2.1.5. One more thing you can do - try to remove vendors folder and then run composer install.

Comment: @Viktor authentication and permissions etc. I have hardcoded all the values from the config file and it works fine. I just want to know why the config file is not being picked up correctly. I know it is hard to say why it does not work, especially if it was working fine for the past 10 months. It seems like nobody had the issue yet.

Comment: It's more difficult, because Sentry close the issues section on GitHub. On other project, I think is better to use Sentinel or move this project to Sentinel for more easier support your project.